# how to comment sentence in sql query - in access 2007?

Tags: ms-access

how to comment sentence in sql query - in access 2007 ?

thank's in advance

Comment: Nees a bit more detail please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://dbaspot.com/forums/ms-access/242934-how-do-you-temporarily-comment-out-sql-code-ms-access-sql-view.html), you can't comment SQL code. To comment VBA code use a single quote (').

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT query_comment_goes_here 
       (SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE 1 = 0), 
       O1.OrderID, O1.CustomerID, O1.OrderDate 
  FROM Orders AS O1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not trying to place a remark on a specific line of the code, but for the overall query, you can enter it in the Description under the query properties.